# ASP.NET Excel Export

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm looking for a way to export an Excel Spreadsheet in a way such that there are multiple values within a cell per Row.

I'm currently using the HtmlTextWriter class to write out the Html into an Excel content type format, but it creates a new Cell for each value within the corresponding Row.

For example, it currently writes out 
Row 1:   RowTitle             Value1
Row 2:                        Value2
Row 3:                        Value3

What I would like is to write everything in one Row.
Row1:    RowTitle             Value1
                              Value2
                              Value3
Row2:

Is this possible - does anyone have any pointers?

My current code is as follows:

```
Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=Compare" + fileName + ".xls");
                    this.EnableViewState = false;
                    System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);
                    this.ClearControls(tblComparison);
                    tblComparison.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);

                    // Embed style rules here so that when opening the file in Excel separately, the styling will stay in place
                    // and not be dependent on an external css file.
                    Response.Write(@"
        <head>
        <title>Compare</title>
        <style>
        #tblComparison { empty-cells:show;border-collapse:collapse;border:none; }
        #tblComparison tr td { vertical-align:top;text-align:center;padding:0px 5px 2px 8px;border-right:1px solid #094A8C;border-bottom:1px dotted #6699FF;font-size:.7em }
        #tblComparison tr td.header { text-align:right;font-weight:bold }
        #tblComparison tr td.header span.note { text-align:right;font-weight:normal;color:#094A8C; }
        #tblComparison tr td div.itrs { display:none }
        #tblComparison tr td textarea { width:20em }
        #tblComparison tr td textarea.objective { height:5em;font-size:.9em }
        #tblComparison tr td select { width:200px;font-size:1em }    
        #tblComparison tr td textarea.comments { height:10em;font-size:.9em }
        #tblComparison tr td textarea.multiline { height:10em;font-size:.9em }
        #tblComparison tr td.requested textarea.comments,
        #tblComparison tr td.requested textarea.objective { background-color:#F2F7FB;border:1px solid gray }
        #tblComparison tr td.requested input { font-size:1em;background-color:#F2F7FB;border:1px solid gray }
        #tblComparison tr .existRequested { background-color:#52697B; color:White;}
        div { font-size: 1em }
        </style>
        </head>
");
                    Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
                    Response.End();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code will help you,

```
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.BufferOutput = true;
    Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    Response.Write("Company, City, Country");
    //IF you want each item in each cell of a row
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Separater(Name) + Separater(City) +Separater(Country) +  "\r\n")
    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Response.OutputStream.Flush();


    private string Separater(string text)
    {
        if (text == null)
        {
            return "\"\",";
        }
        return "\"" + text.Replace("\"", "'") + "\"" + ",";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into this tomorrow and let you know if it does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the data for the table from a collection or dataset, you can use spreadsheet class to create your excel on the fly and format it from code behind the way you want.

Some thing like this. [OWC](http://forums.asp.net/p/1808505/5002061.aspx/1?Create%20excel%20sheet%20on%20fly)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Export", I assume that you mean that you want to be able to create a speadsheet for the user to download.  If that is what you mean then you might want to have a look at "CarlogAg Excel Xml Writer" - http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/

If what you mean is that you want to be able to create a grid on the page that will contain the data that is in an Excel spreadsheet, then you might want to consider reading the data in using the "Excel Data Reader" - http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/.  That will give you a DataTable which you can then bind an ASP.Net  to it, like this... http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-Bind-GridView-to-DataTable.aspx